# CKEditor CDN and config for inline editing

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So, I have a page with div's that have `contenteditable=true`, and I load `//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js` which makes them editable with CKEditor - but since I do not use `CKEDITOR.replace()` I can't send along a configuration for the editor's. How do I set the toolbar configuration for CKEditor that is being loaded for contenteditable fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CDN, I'm afraid only option is to use

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
CKEDITOR.inline("div_id", { customConfig: "config.js" });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Inline editor

If you wish to have inline editor, you can use [`CKEDITOR.inline`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline) method to converse such div into inline editor, you can pass regular configuration as object in second argument. Example with configuration which change ui colour you can do like that ([full example](https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/vWwqrd)):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor', {
  uiColor: '66FFFF'
} );
```

## Divarea editor

Another option is to use divarea editor. In such case you use regular [`CKEDITOR.replace`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) method and you have to add **`divarea`** plugin.
Example implementation below with link to codepen implementation.
https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/YEbode As you can see css from main website are also applied inside the editor.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
  uiColor: '66FFFF',
  extraPlugins: 'divarea'
} );
```